# Missing Argument for 'Wait' Parameter Defined in JEA Roles Capabilities File

Tags: powershell, parameters, wait, jea

I'm building a JEA profile and defining the VisibleCmdlets allowed in the [Role Capabilities File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-psrolecapabilityfile?view=powershell-7.2).

```
...
VisibleCmdlets = ...
  @{
    Name = 'Get-Content'
    Parameters =
      @{ Name = 'Tail' },
      @{ Name = 'Wait' },
      @{ Name = 'Path'; ValidatePattern = '.*<keyword>.*' }
  },
...
```

This is to be used to restrict the user's etsn session to get-content for files under a directory path containing the specified 'keyword'.

Example:

```
get-content -tail 10 -wait <keyword path>.log
```

I've never had issues with this command when running it on the server, but when testing over etsn with the JEA profile loaded I'm getting this error:

> Missing an argument for parameter 'Wait'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again.

Initially I thought it was because the '-wait' parameter was a "SwitchParameter Struct" type, but I switched it out with '-force' which is the same parameter type in the roles capabilities file, and the command completes successfully.

I've also tried setting the value of Wait to null after some googling, but got similar results.

```
@{ Name = 'Wait'; Value = '' },
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For switch parameters you want `@{ Name = 'Wait'; Value = $true }`

Comment: Update,

I did try ```@{ Name = 'Wait'; Value = $true }```, but still got the error.

I was able to get this to work if I defined the value in the get-content command ```-wait:$True```, but this is not ideal because we don't want to overly complicate the end user experience with "arbitrary gotcha's".

Comment: Not knowing JEA: Is it necessary to explicitly allow the `-Wait` parameter (if you don't need to constrain its values, which doesn't really apply to `[switch]` parameters)?

Comment: If we don't specify the ```-wait``` parameters in the capabilities file you'll get this error ```A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'wait'```.

Comment: If you don't specify any parameters you can bypass this issue entirely with VisibleCmdlets as it accepts any parameters and arguments passed. Though since we want to be able to restrict what commands can be executed where we're needing to specify these parameters. With the testing we've done so far JEA seems to require we specify all parameters, that might be used, with the command. What's odd about all this is if we add ```@{ Name = 'Force' }```, which is the same ```[switch]``` parameter type, it completes successfully with no argument needed.